# how to know android.widget.EditText editable set to true

Tags: android, android-edittext

I can see in the **Eclipse** debugger that there is a parameter editable for

`android.widget.EditText.`

How can I find that **android.widget.EditText** editable is set to true?

Comment: try this `editText.isEnabled();` if true then EditText is editable otherwise not editable.

Comment: what editable parameter are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check:

```
boolean EditText.isEnabled()
void EditText.setEnabled(boolean enabled)
```